# create a sliding window of input data from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have to create a sliding window of input data with `window size = 3`

**Dataframe**

```
     0   1
 0   1   2
 1   3   4
 2   5   6
 3   7   8
```

**Desired output:**

```
     0   1   2   3   4   5
 0   1   2   NA  NA  NA  NA
 1   3   4   1   2   NA  NA
 2   5   6   3   4   1   2
 3   7   8   5   6   3   4
```

I used `data.values.flatten()` but it converts all rows in `dataframe` in `nested list`.
How can I create a sliding window of input data (of desired window length) from `dataframe`

Comment: What you described with your output just looks like `df.shift`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `concat`:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df.shift(i) for i in range(3)], axis=1)

# rename columns
new_df.columns = np.arange(new_df.shape[1])
```

output:

```
   0  1    2    3    4    5
0  1  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  3  4  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
2  5  6  3.0  4.0  1.0  2.0
3  7  8  5.0  6.0  3.0  4.0
```